# Trying to automatically insert a foreign key value into my mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key, database-table

I am new with PHP and MySQL and need help...

Im cant seem to get my head around how to automatically insert a foreign key into a table in my database. The primary key gets added as 'id' in my 'mem' table but I want this same id to be added to a foreign key in my 'location' table. Can anyone please help?

I have two tables...

'mem table' 
id, username, email.

```
  |    1    |    2    |    3    |
  |   paul  |   john  | francis |       
  | paul@gm.| john@gm.|francis@.|
```

'location table' 
id, location, user_id << forign key

```
  |    1    |    2    |    3    |
  |  leeds  |liverpool| london  |       
  |    ?    |    ?    |    ?    |
```

how do I get the 'id' in the user table to automatically get inserted here as a foreign key?

Im using this php code to insert the data...

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO mem (username, country, state, city, accounttype, email, password, signupdate) 
        VALUES('$username','$country','$state','$city','$accounttype','$email','$hashedPass', now())")      or die(mysql_error());
$id = mysql_insert_id();

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO location (location) 
VALUES('$location')") or die(mysql_error());
$user_id = mysql_insert_id();
```

Im getting this error when I submit the form...
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mem`.`location`, CONSTRAINT `location_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `location` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

your FK is in the wrong direction. In the moment it says: "Every entry in user table MUST have a entry in location table." You try to insert in the user table, without creating a location entry first. So the FK fails.

solution:
Set the FK on the location table "user_id -> users.user_id" so it means "every user_id on the location table should have an entry in the users table.". The only Problem is: the "ON DELETE CASCADE" is no longer working, when you delete a entry in the users table... - This can be solved with a database trigger (PSEUDOCODE) "BEFORE delete FROM users DELETE FROM locations WHERE user_id" or you just do 2 queries in PHP. (which is the easier solution. 1st delete location row, 2nd the user row.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but can I do this using the php code or do I use a sql query?

Comment: this is a database Problem. You have to change on the database.

Use:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html

OR:

PHP-solution:

    mysql_query('DELETE FROM location WHERE user_id ='. $user_id);

    mysql_query('DELETE FROM user WHERE user_id = '. $user_id);

Comment: Im not as concerned about that just yet, im still stuck on setting the foreign key.. how do I set it as users.user_id?

Comment: do you use phpMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench? that makes it a lot easier. Otherwise you have to use this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: Im currently using phpMyAdmin, still very confused!

Comment: navigate in PHP my ad to the "structure" tab of "location" table. Click on "connection / foreign key." left of the "print" button. (sorry i have the german version so I can't check the correct english)  now you see a list with the field of the current table and a dropdown with fields of other tables. - This means the field of the current table could ONLY contain values of the referenced field.

Comment: a short example of FKs: Table "user" contains ids "1, 2, 3, 4, 5". You have a FK from locations.id referencing "user.id" - So inserting a row with id "3" would be fine. Inserting onw with id "6" would result in an FK error. In phpmyadmin this is easy to check: click the "insert" button. Fields with an FK will automagicly show a dropdown with possible values from the referenced table.